# trait is not visible inside another package scala

Tags: scala

I have a PipeStages class inside org.analytics package and I have trait Pipe outside of this package.I want to extend from Pipe trait within org.analytics but it dosen't works.But I can use pipe outside that package

```
org.analytics
|
|----- PipeStages

Pipe
```

Comment: How do you import it?

Answer (score 0):

Trait Pipe belongs by default to the "default"  package therefore any class you create in the default package (ie without specifying any package name at the top of the class definition) can see/access this trait. When defining any new class in your org.analytics package you have to import the necessary traits that are not located in the same  package